# Decode (and render) H264 RTP packets

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, rtp

I wrote some code that stores on the disk some RTP packets with H264 stream. I would like to be able to extract H264 data from the RTP packets and render that data somewhere to test and see if my code works. How can I do this?

I suppose gstreamer can give me a hand. If I store the packets in a file on the disk, would it be possible using gstreamer to extract, decode and render somewhere? Or to create an h264 video file to play it and see what's inside?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to capture RTP stream to file capture.rtp:

```
gst-launch -v -e \
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
    ! x264enc bitrate=200 \
    ! rtph264pay \
    ! filesink location=capture.rtp
```

and this to decode and render it:

```
gst-launch -v \
    filesrc location=capture.rtp \
    ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 \
    ! rtph264depay               \
    ! ffdec_h264                 \
    ! xvimagesink
```

Comment: Thanks, this example works additionally i would add more reference to this for other readers and myself. I also installed (ffdec_h264, x264enc was not available in my system): $ yum  -y installgstreamer-ffmpeg.i686 gstreamer-plugins-bad.i686 gstreamer-plugins-ugly.i686